# How to create a "global" immutable List<T> list that can be binarySearched

Tags: c#, list, readonly, binary-search

The problem: When my program stars I create a `List<myClass> myList` and fill it with objects. Those objects are created with date from files. And after that I don't want to change that list nor access the files again. But I need to access that List in a lot of classes / methods

The solution I came up with: create the `List<myClass> myList` as a private in a static class and fill it using the constructor of my static class, and access it only with properties that return a myList.AsReadOnly(). This way I can't change the actual list. But the return of the AsReadOnly is a IList, right? I was checking the IList on MSDN and there's no BinarySearch method... Which would make the whole thing quite slow.

How can I solve this issue? Copying the IList return to a normal List so I can sort and BinarySearch it? Or maybe change the whole "myList.AsReadOnly()" approach? I'm open to all kinds of suggestions and approaches ^^ Changing the whole code is not a problem.

edit:

1. TL;DR how can I make a "global" List that can be access by any method / class in my program, that can be sorted using the List.Sort method, that can be binarysearched AND that can't have it's contents altered (neither by adding nor removing elements) after it was created.
2. As soon as I get back home I'll post some code.

Comment: At the moment this question is bad subjective, show some actual code and it might be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, depends on personal preference. This is mine, as an example:

```
private List<string> _MyList = new List<string>();

private void InitializeList()
{
    //code here to fill list.

    //Keep in mind, that binary search works on sorted lists.
    _MyList.Sort(/* Place your object comparer here.  */);
}



//Make a copy in an array.
public string[] MyListAsArray
{
    get { return _MyList.ToArray(); }
}


public int GetBinarySearchIndex(string value)
{
    return Array.BinarySearch(MyListAsArray, value/*, Place your object comparer here.  */);
}
```

Comment: I like your approach, as soon as I get home I'll try your method. But it looks really nice and efficient! Thank you!

Comment: +1: Simple and easy to prove to be correct. Note that returning cloned array guarantees immutability of original list, but comes at potentially large performance cost for cloning  - make sure this tradeoff  work for your case. Otherwise creating custom R/O wrapper may be an option (or use `ImmutableList` as suggested in +1 akton's answer).

Answer (score 7):

If you are using later versions of .Net, instead of using AsReadOnly(), use an [`ImmutableList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It cannot be modified once created but has the [`BinarySearch()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method you are looking for. It is also potentially more efficient if you want to subdivide the list or access it from multiple threads.

Comment: Is that built into 4.5 or do you have to download it from NuGet? The MSDN page lists the NuGet link to it.

Comment: @TyCobb It is included in .Net 4.5.1 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574802.aspx) but needs to be downloaded via NuGet for earlier versions.

Comment: But the ImmutableList<T> has a .Add method ._.

Comment: @Trauer All modification methods to an ImmutableList<T> return new lists. By comparison, the traditional List<T> modification methods modify the list in place.

Comment: Oh nice! I was just looking at the methods/properties of the ImmutableList but I didn't check what the actually do or how they work. Very nice approach too!

Comment: Looks like it gives you the same list if the object is already in the list: `A new immutable list with the object added, or the current list if it already contains the specified object.` So I suppose it also doubles as a unique list depending on your type.